# PHP code runs automatically in Javascript when not needed

Tags: javascript, php, html

Inside a **PHP/HTML** page i'm trying to start a session in php and then set a value to a session variable, and i'm trying that inside a Javascript function, and in this function there is a if statement, but the php code inside the if statement runs automatically when i go to the page immediately, when i want the code to run only when the user accept the terms...

Here is my code :

**HTML :**

```
<label>                                        
    <input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms-checkbox">             
    <font color="#090909" size="+1">I agree to the Terms and Conditions.</font>
</label>
```

**Javascript :**

```
if(document.getElementById("terms-checkbox").checked){
    <?php session_start(); $_SESSION["ITA"] = "Yes"; ?>
    window.open('DL.php?App=STOPit');
}
```

So when i open the php page that contains that previous Javascript code, the $_SESSION["ITA"] variable will be equals to "Yes" even that the condition is not met yet.

Hope someone can help me with that.

Comment: It's natural. You have to put php in a php conditonal not a JavaScript conditional.

Comment: You mean you are trying to run server code in the client? Never gonna happen. PHP produces your document, then you need to fire a requestb to interact with the server.

Comment: Sounds right, but how i'm gonna do it, inside `DL.php` i'm checking the session variable and download a file when it's only equals to "Yes" and then reset its value to "No".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your better understanding `php` runs on the server side and `javascript` runs on the client side.

What you are trying to do is possible if you submit the data using a `form` or you have to make an `ajax` call using `javascript`.

Below is one way of doing something similar.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['terms'])) {
        $_SESSION["ITA"] = "Yes";
        header('Location: DL.php?App=STOPit');
    }
?>

<form action="<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="post">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms-checkbox">
        <font color="#090909" size="+1">I agree to the Terms and Conditions.</font>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </label>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any security approaches like that?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by that? Are you asking if this is a secure way or not?

Comment: Yes that's what i meant, sorry.

Comment: Well security is another big topic. But this is just fine if you are not working on a very large scale application. This is how we normally pass data from our `html forms` to `php`.

Comment: Thanks that's kind of work, but when i submit, it throws `Fatal error: Call to undefined function open() in /home/u218009432/public_html/Apps/Free/STOPit.php on line 5`, and the line is : `window.open('DL.php?App=STOPit');`

Comment: Sorry my bad. In `php` there is no `window.open`, inorder to redirect to another page/url you need use `header('location')`. I just updated my code.

Comment: OMG, hehehe..... How did i miss that too, man programming is driving me crazy.

Comment: haha it's normal to a programmer :-) This is how we learn and grow!

Comment: Congratulations! Please mark it as an answer if it helped you.

Comment: Oops.... I forgot ;p

Comment: *UPDATED* worked like i want --> http://mousaalfhaily.esy.es/Apps/Free/STOPit/

Answer (score 4):

That's not how PHP and Javascript work.

PHP runs on the server before anything else. JS runs on the client side.

Without further information:

I suppose your JS code is not a file, but a inline script on the same HTML/PHP page. When your user requests the HTML page, PHP parses it, including the tags inside your JS code.

If you want PHP to do something based on a user action on the browser (`document.getElementById`) you have to take other routes. Maybe using Ajax, for example -- so your PHP code can do something.

Comment: Thanks, you've been the first one, and i did get some knowledge right there :)

Answer (score 1):

**Always** start your PHP `session_start()` on the top of your PHP script file.

```
<?php

session_start();

?>

Here you can continue with your HTML/CSS/JavaScript codes
but the above is mandatory in order to start a session within
your PHP project.
```

Otherwise you'll be sending header information after the output buffering happend, and you'll end up with an error like this:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /some/file.php:12) in /some/file.php on line 23
```

When you have properly initialized a session handler as I described, you can use or do:

```
$_SESSION['item-name'] = 'value'; // to set a value of a specific session item

echo $_SESSION['item-name'];      // retrieve it's value and output it

unset($_SESSION['item-name']);    // to delete it from the $_SESSION container
```

Comment: Thanks, i know what you said and that's right, but here it seems to work because if i checked the value of the session variable, it will be equals to "Yes", so the session is starting.

Comment: I still don't understand what you want to achieve with PHP's session inside a JavaScript callback?

Comment: Inside `DL.php` i'm checking the session variable and download a file when it's only equals to "Yes" and then reset its value to "No".

Comment: You should either use Cookies instead, or have an additional AJAX callback after a user changes the checkbox.

Comment: Thanks, i was thing of using Cookies too.