# can i call a php function using onclick

Tags: javascript, php, onclick

Click me

```
  <?php 
        function myfun(){
             echo "Hello World";
        }
        ?>
```

I really don't know how does it work i just want to learn php. Please help me by solving my problem. when i'm clicking the button it's showing nothing.

Comment: Try using Ajax  To do this

Comment: My answer here might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43035050/php-code-runs-automatically-in-javascript-when-not-needed/43035202?noredirect=1#comment73157099_43035202

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't invoke a server side function (PHP) in a client side language (JavaScript).

However, you can emulate this by using AJAX and requesting an external webpage:

### index.html

```js
$("button").click(function () {
  $(this).attr("disabled",true);
  $.get("http://neil.computer/stack/test.php",function (data) {
    $(document.body).html(data);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Load HTML!</button>
```

### test.php

```
<?php

function myfun(){
     echo "Hello World";
}

myfun();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side application so there, so you cannot directly call it onClick() because that event happens on the client side.

However, you can call it via JavaScript!  More specifically aJax.

[Here's a good place to start](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/)

Here's a quick example from [What is Sleep`s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19323685/7607701)

AJax:

```
function callPHP() {
    $.ajax ({
        url: "yourPageName.php",
        data: { action : assign }, //optional
        success: function( result ) {
            //do something after you receive the result
        }
    }
```

PHP:

```
if ($_POST["action"] == "assign")
{
    assign(your parameters); //You need to put the parameters you want to pass in
                             //the data field of the ajax call, and use $_POST[]
                             //to get them 
}
```